Flask "send_from_directory" always sends files of one type as attachment
I am trying to return images to this route with send_from_directory, every image type works, it displays the img in the browser correctly, but .webp images don't? If i access this route with an .webp image as argument the browser always downloads it directly as if the "as_attachment" parameter was set to true, which is not.
@bp.route("/<imagename>", methods=["GET"]) def get_image(imagename): return send_from_directory(current_app.config["IMAGES_DIR"], imagename, as_attachment=False) 
Tried with every other image file extension, everyone worked normally displaying the image in the browser.

Apparently the problem was the image itself, even though it is a normal .webp image for some reason it behaves differently from others.

You have to define the mimetype for webp images.
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('image/webp', '.webp')


So i tried your solution and a lot more and nothing worked, so i tried with other images of .webp and it worked normally.. Apparently the problem was the image itself, even though it was an normal webp image, so i don't know what is the problem with this image exacly that makes her be downloaded directly as an attachment
